# Can't access unity package manager on ubuntu

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently installed unity on my laptop, but I realized that I can't access some of the features like package manager and asset store directly from unity which is a bit annoying. I'll leave you a screen shot of it.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I am on kubuntu

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use unity on Ubuntu but I think they took the same ui from the windows layout but they didn't implement the asset store feature on the Linux based version

Comment: Yes I guess it is just not implemented on the ubuntu version